# Use two different databases to replicate data & serve reads most performantly according to data suited for each

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nosql, cassandra

I have a 2GB Digital Ocean VPS with 2 CPUs, to host a social network app written in Java. Right now my app stores data to Cassandra, but Cassandra is a new technology & not as reliable  as MySQL that has been for years, also my experience in managing Cassandra as a DBA is not much. So I wanted to change my primary datasource back to MySQL but since some of the data is stored just schemaless, for e.g. there are lists specific to each user that are easily stored in Cassandra. For this type of  data, I would use Cassandra as primary database.

So, to sum up, I would replicate my entire data in both the databases. Data will be written to both databases but read from where I can get it most performantly. This will help me in case when the entire Cassandra cluster goes down I can serve from mysql or vice versa. Is this usually done & recommended to do ?

*(Right now I have a single 2 GB VPS that would host my app as well as the databases)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we never see that people managing two separate database system just for purpose of data lost and recovery, always better to rely upon replication or mirroring of any of database system. Both are good and providing enough solution for replication so better you will choose any single one of them.